# Recognizing when the user is driving, walking, biking

Tags: java, android, ios, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to find the most reliable way to identify if the user is driving, walking, biking or is stationary. I am going to use this in an Android application. I would prefer to avoid GPS as much as possible.

Please let me know what algorithms worked for you, their advantages and disadvatages. Thanks!

Comment: My first thought would be to have speed thresholds and some number of "shakes" detected by the device for each transportation method. But you will probably have to use GPS to identify the user's speed.

Answer (score 1):

Google has an API for this in Google Play Services.  Check out https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi.html

I wouldn't suggest coding it on your own, its not easy (I had a version about a year before Google did, it was buggy and battery draining).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried it,  but the accuracy  is  not that  great.  The confidence metric is usually too low to be relied on.

Comment: THe confidence is low because it isn't an easy question.  If they're moving 10 miles an hour are the biking, or driving slowly through a parking lot?  If they stop for 30 seconds are they done driving or at a red light?  What about 60 seconds?  120?  Its all guess work really.  And if you're asking here rather than implementing a brilliant idea of your own, do you really think you're going to do better than they did with a team of people and serious time spent?

Answer (score 0):

You probably will never get a completely accurate result, but a reasonable estimate could be determined using

```
- GPS to identify speed
- Is the charger plugged in
- is the phone off, or on screensaver
- is the movement detector going off a lot - likely walking but may be driving on dirt road
```

I was playing with a simplistic version of this as follows (sorry code is in Python)

```
def inspect_phone(self):
    self.phone_gps_lat = 137.0000  # get from phone
    self.phone_gps_lng = 100.0000  # get from phone
    self.phone_moving = False      #  get from phone
    self.phone_move_dist_2_mn = 4
    self.phone_on_charge = True
    self.screen_saver = False
    #-------------------------------
    phone_status = ''
    if self.phone_on_charge == True:
        phone_status += 'Phone is charging'
        if self.phone_moving == True:
            phone_status += ', driving in Car'
        else:
            phone_status += ', sitting still'
    else:
        if self.screen_saver == False:
            phone_status += 'Phone is being used'
        else:
            phone_status += 'Phone is off'
        if self.phone_moving == True:
            if self.phone_move_dist_2_mn < 5:
                phone_status += ', going for Walk'
            elif  self.phone_move_dist_2_mn > 500:
                phone_status += ', flying on Plane'
            else:    
                phone_status += ', riding on ' + transport['Public']
    return phone_status
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a small logic to get the best polylines for each activity and optimize the draw, since we need certain quantity of latitudes and longitudes in order to draw the best track that the user has made.

Lets say when the user press to start a new activity it will prompt 3 options, run, walk or biking.

This method takes what the user has selected and updates the locationRequest for each one.

```
 public void setTrackActivity(long interval, long fastInterval) {

            //Update the locationRequest intervals for each different Activity
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(interval);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(fastInterval);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    }
```

- For walking I set the locationRequest intervals within 6 seconds
  delay for each request.
- For runing I set the locationRequest intervals within 2 seconds delay
  for each request.
- For runing I set the locationRequest intervals within 1 second delay
  for each request.

Then, to save up more polylines when drawing the map, I take the same concept. If an user is walking it will trace a polyline each 30 polylines that have been made

```
 public void drawTrack(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        googleMap.clear();  //Clearing markers and polylines

        PolylineOptions polyline_options = new PolylineOptions().addAll(mLinkedList)
                .color(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorAccent)).width(Constants.POLYLINE_WIDTH).geodesic(true);

        // Adding the polyline to the map
        Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(polyline_options);
        // set the zindex so that the poly line stays on top of my tile overlays
        polyline.setZIndex(1000);
        // we add each polyline to an array of polylines
        mPolylinesArray.add(polyline);
        // We add the latest latlang points we got
        mLatLngArray.add(mLinkedList.getLast());

        //If we have made 30 polylines we store 1 line starting from that first point to the last, so we can save 28 polylines and draw one instead of having so many points for lets say 10 meters, this value must change depending on the activity, if biking, runing or walking
        if (mLatLngArray.size() % 30 == 0) {
            // First we delete all polylines saved at the array
            for (Polyline pline : mPolylinesArray) {
                pline.remove();
            }
            // We create a new polyline based on the first and last latlang from the 30 we took
            Polyline routeSoFar = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().color(Color.GREEN).width(Constants.POLYLINE_WIDTH).geodesic(true));
            // Draw the polyline
            routeSoFar.setPoints(mLatLngArray);
            // set the zindex so that the poly line stays on top of my tile overlays
            routeSoFar.setZIndex(1000);
            // Clear polyline array
            mPolylinesArray.clear();
            // Add polyline to array
            mPolylinesArray.add(routeSoFar);
        }

}
```

Where `mLinkedList` is an `LinkedList<LatLng>` so we can have the first and last element (if you want to draw a custom marker when activity starts and when activity finish )

`mPolylinesArray` is an array of `Polylines` `ArrayList<Polyline>`